# array_intersect a variable amount of arrays

Tags: php, arrays, variables, loops, array-intersect

I am creating a faceted search, and I'm am trying to use `array_intersect` to compare the arrays and find the inputs that match.

The problem is that I will have a variable amount of arrays at anytime depending on what filters the user has selected:

`$array_1, $array_2, $array_3` etc...

How do I create an `array_intersect` function that is dynamic in this sense?

This is what I've tried:

```
$next_array = 0;
for($i = 0; $i < $array_count; $i++) {
    $next_array++;
    if ($i == 0) {
        $full_array = ${array_.$i};
    } else {
        if(!empty(${cvp_array.$next_array})) {
            $full_array = array_intersect($full_array, ${cvp_array_.$next_array});
        }
    }
}
```

------------- EDIT -------------

I'll try to narrow down my goal a bit more:

If the user clicks three filters, this results in three arrays being created with each having individual results:

`Array_1 ( [0] => 2, [1] => 4, [2] => 6 )`

`Array_2 ( [0] => 1, [1] => 4, [2] => 6 )`

`Array_3 ( [0] => 6, [1] => 7, [2] => 8 )`

I need code that will find the number that is in ALL of the arrays. And if there is no common number then it would end as false or something. In the case above, I'd need it to retrieve 6. If it was only the first two arrays, it would return 4 and 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, turn those arrays into an array of arrays. Then you can use [`array_reduce`](http://php.net/array-reduce) combined with `array_intersect` to reduce a variable amount of arrays down to one.

Comment: Sorry, trying real hard to visualize what you mean by combining `array_reduce` with `array_intersect` - Maybe an example would help?

Comment: Something like this: `$out = array_reduce($in,function(&$a,$b) {$a = array_intersect($a,$b);},Array());` - All that's left for you to do is put all your indiviual arrays into one big array called `$in`

Comment: I put all my arrays in an array of arrays called `$in`, but it yields this error: `unexpected T_FUNCTION` - thanks again for your time

Comment: Ah, you're using an old version of PHP. Well, you can either update (always a good idea) or use `create_function('&$a,$b','$a = array_intersect($a,$b);');` instead.

Answer (score 16):

Try this:

```
$fullArray = array($array1, $array2, $array3...);
call_user_func_array('array_intersect', $fullArray);
```

Comment: explaining why would help this answer

Comment: This function throws a warning if $fullArray has < 2 arrays in it. I've wrapped it into:
if ( count ($fullArray) > 1) ) { ...call_user_func_array... }

Answer (score 5):

One can use:

```
$intersect = array_intersect(...$fullArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can turn those array to a single array named `$total_array` by using `array_combine()`,
then use `array_intersect($full_array, $total_array)`. I hope this useful

Comment: see my edit up above - I need to compare each array and find the values that match in ALL the arrays.