# Issue with array_intersect

Tags: php

I have a problem in this code. I must have the intersection between tables whose count is more than 0. Then I used the function `array_interset()` but when I use the condition to count I have a problem in this code:

```
$iheb1 = 
array_intersect( 
    if(count($tab0)>0) { $tab0, }
    if(count($tab1)>0) { $tab1, }
    if(count($tab2)>0) { $tab2, } 
    if(count($tab3)>0) { $tab3, }
    if(count($tab4)>0) { $tab4, }
    if(count($tab5)>0) { $tab5, }
    if(count($tab6)>0) { $tab6 }
);
```

Comment: No, you have many problems with that code.

Comment: Please revise your code formatting, typos and add a description of *why* your code is not working, and what errors you get. Also, your title is in french, please use a more descriptive, english title

Comment: Please have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

There many issues here. The big one being your if statements in the parameters of array_intersect.

Try this:

First add all of the arrays to an array or arrays (i used $full_array).

```
$array_to_test = array();

foreach($full_array as $arr){
    if(count($arr)>0){
        array_push($array_to_test, $arr);
    }
}
$iheb1 = array_reduce($array_to_test,function(&$a,$b) {$a = array_intersect($a,$b);},Array());
```

I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12381085/array-intersect-a-variable-amount-of-arrays) to yours and this seems to be working.

Comment: i like to have the intersection just between  arrays whitch have length>0

Comment: It does answer why he is getting an error. When it was posted initially there was not more information as to what the end goal was so this was the only thing to answer.

Comment: i like to determinate the intersection just betwwen table whitch have count >0

Comment: i used this code $array_to_test = array();
$fullArray = array($tab0,$tab1,$tab2,$tab3,$tab4,$tab5,$tab6,$tab7);
foreach($full_array as $arr){
    if(count($arr)>0){
        array_push($array_to_test, $arr);
    }
}
$iheb1 = array_reduce($array_to_test,function(&$a,$b) {$a = array_intersect($a,$b);},Array());

Comment: we'll need more information than that. Is it giving you an error? What other debugging steps have you gone through to test it out?